# New variable in plt.streamplot() broken_streamlines does not work, how to fix this?

Tags: python, matplotlib, variables, github, plot

I need my streamlines on the plot in Python to be continuous. I am using plt.streamplot() which by default plots broken lines. I have found that in the source code someone has already made up a variable which is called broken_streamlines and it can be True or False, by default it is True [broken_streamlines](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/main/lib/matplotlib/streamplot.py).

In documentation of [matplotlib.pyplot.streamplot](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.streamplot.html) it does not exist, but in documentation of [matplotlib.axes.Axes.streamplot](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.streamplot.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.streamplot) it does exist.

Unfortunatelly it does not work neither in plt.streamplot() nor Axes.streamplot() and I got communicate:

> TypeError: streamplot() got an unexpected keyword argument 'broken_streamlines'

What can I do about this? I have been looking for other solution to force the lines to be continuous (eg. density, start points, minlenght etc.) but it occurs that my data is very difficult to manipulate. What possibly can I do wrong (Python3 is already actualized)? I already tried it on MacOS and Linux.

Comment: What version of matplotlib are you using? The two documentation links you have for stream plot are pointing to different versions, so that probably explains why one of them has the new option `broken_streamlines` and one doesn't.

Comment: Indeed, digging a little further, it seems it does not appear in the current stable version (3.5), but is in the developer version (3.6)

Comment: I use matplotlib 3.5.2 version, so this probably is a core of a problem. Is there any chance to get to developer version?

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/installing/index.html#installing-from-source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade your version of the `matplotlib` package by running `pip install matplotlib --upgrade`

The `broken_streamlines` parameter was introduced in Matplotlib 3.6.0 - see the relevant changelog entry below:
https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/prev_whats_new/whats_new_3.6.0.html#streamplot-can-disable-streamline-breaks

Also see the changes in the documentation of the `streamplot` function:

- version 3.5.3 https://matplotlib.org/3.5.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.streamplot.html
- version 3.6.0 https://matplotlib.org/3.6.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.streamplot.html