# How to handle (complete or totally remove) incomplete trajectories drawn in a phase portrait?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

For the following nonlinear system

```
xdot = x + exp(-y)
ydot = -y
```

whose phase portrait is:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xvalues, yvalues = np.meshgrid(np.arange(-5, 5, 0.1), np.arange(-5, 5, 0.1))
xdot = xvalues - np.exp(-yvalues)
ydot = - yvalues
plt.streamplot(xvalues, yvalues, xdot, ydot, color='r', linewidth=0.5, density=1.2)
plt.show()
```

However, some of the trajectories are (visually-unappealing) incomplete arcs like the blue ones highlighted below:

[image]

I need to (i) eliminate those arcs off the plot or (ii) make them complete just like, e.g., the black one. How can I achieve this?

can I achieve the following changes

Comment: Can you try `broken_streamlines=False` in [`plt.streamplot`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.streamplot.html#matplotlib.pyplot.streamplot)?

Comment: @medium-dimensional: Adding the option you noted to `streamplot` throws `TypeError: streamplot() got an unexpected keyword argument 'broken_streamlines'` using my `matplotlib 3.5.3`.

Comment: Yes, same with me. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73119873/new-variable-in-plt-streamplot-broken-streamlines-does-not-work-how-to-fix-th.

Answer (score 0):

As of Matplotlib version 3.6.0, an optional parameter `broken_streamlines` [has been added](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/prev_whats_new/whats_new_3.6.0.html#streamplot-can-disable-streamline-breaks) for disabling streamline breaks.

Adding it to your snippet (and halving the density to compensate for the visual clutter) produces the following result:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xvalues, yvalues = np.meshgrid(np.arange(-5, 5, 0.1), np.arange(-5, 5, 0.1))
xdot = xvalues - np.exp(-yvalues)
ydot = - yvalues
plt.streamplot(xvalues, yvalues, xdot, ydot, color='r', linewidth=0.5, density=0.6, broken_streamlines=False)
plt.show()
```

[image: a stream plot with continuous streamlines]

### Note

This parameter just extends the streamlines which were originally drawn (as in the question). This means that the streamlines in the modified plot above look uneven, due to the way the streamline start points are chosen (see the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.streamplot.html) for the `density` parameter of `matplotlib.pyplot.streamplot` for more details on how streamline start points are chosen).

For accurate streamline density, consider using [matplotlib.pyplot.contour](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.contour.html), but be aware that `contour` does not show arrows.